# swift - central writing characteristic to Peripheral

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I have connected to two iPhones and found the services and characteristics in it. I am facing problems in sending write requests from central and receiving response from peripheral. I have written the code below to write data in central and received data in Peripheral. But the function `didReceiveWriteRequests` didn't execute. I don't know Why didn't work.

In central view write, the data code:

```
func writeValue(data:NSData){
   if let discoveredPeripheral = discoveredPeripheral{
        if let deviceCharacteristics = deviceCharacteristics{
            discoveredPeripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: deviceCharacteristics, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
        }     
    }    
}
```

and in peripheral view, the receive code:

```
func peripheralManager(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager!, didReceiveWriteRequests requests: [AnyObject]!) {

    println("didReceiveWriteRequests")
    println("\(requests.count)")
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please identify the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.  Could you elaborate on "didn't work"?  Thanks!

Comment: It means peripheral didn't catch central's data. "func peripheralManager" doesn't work.